# Specify Multiple Images for a Product in an X-Cart File

Tags: x-cart

I'm creating an X-Cart file for a number of products from data in a SQL database, each product may have multiple images.  Is there a way of adding multiple images per product.  I've consulted the file specification [here](https://help.x-cart.com/X-Cart:CSV_Format_for_Various_Data_Types) but that suggests there is only one image per product?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the same approach as in this module
https://help.x-cart.com/X-Cart:Detailed_Product_Images

More complex solution is https://help.x-cart.com/X-Cart:Product_Options#Managing_Product_Variants